# XML Object array deserialization with namespaces

Tags: c#, arrays, xml-serialization

I am trying to deserialize some XML which includes an array of objects. 
When everything is on the same namespace it works, however the response I am getting includes additional namespaces and at that point it all stops working.

This is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BodyTest>
<ProjectTests xmlns:c="https://example.com/schemas">
    <c:ProjectT>
        <c:Address>Eva Peron Ave s St</c:Address>
    </c:ProjectT>
    <c:ProjectT>
        <c:Address>Eva Peron Ave ones St</c:Address>
    </c:ProjectT>
    <c:ProjectT>
        <c:Address>Eva Peron AveJones St</c:Address>
    </c:ProjectT>
    <c:ProjectT>
        <c:Address>Eva Peron A Jones St</c:Address>
    </c:ProjectT>
</ProjectTests>
</BodyTest>
```

These are my classes:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "BodyTest")]
public class BodyTest
{
    [XmlArray("ProjectTests")]
    public HashSet<ProjectT> ProjectTests { get; set; }
}

[XmlType("ProjectT", Namespace = "https://example.com/schemas")]
public class ProjectT
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

I am simply running this to deserialize:

```
//no data
string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\testPage2.xml";

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
reader.ReadToDescendant("BodyTest");

System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(BodyTest));
BodyTest fetchPage = (BodyTest)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

I don't get any serialization errors but my hashset comes back empty.

If I build out the same xml WITHOUT namespaces then it works.
Likewise if I use namespaces but don't make it an array it also works.

Please can someone offer some ideas.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue. I needed the following attribute on the array

```
[XmlArrayItemAttribute("ProjectT", Namespace = "https://example.com/schemas", IsNullable = false)]
```

as follows:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "BodyTest")]
public class BodyTest
{
    [XmlArray("ProjectTests")]
    [XmlArrayItemAttribute("ProjectT", Namespace = "https://example.com/schemas", IsNullable = false)]
    public HashSet<ProjectT> ProjectTests { get; set; }
}
```